# create random slices of an array to assign to another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose, mongoose-schema, array.prototype.map

I am creating a Mongoose seed and creating documents of "pets". For every shelter in my db (a document of 20) I want to insert a random number of the array of pets created in the first lines of my code.

I am looking to get:

> Shelter 1: { dogs: ["dog.id1", "dog.id18"] }...Shelter 20: { dogs: ["dog.id14", "dog.id2", "dog.id17"] }

Where the number and id's of those pets are randomized.

I have tried with the code below but: While I don't get any errors, I am only getting the first two shelters with "dogs", the rest appears blank: like this:

> Shelter 1: { dogs: ["dog.id1", "dog.id18"] }, Shelter 2: { dogs: ["dog.id2"] }...Shelter 3-20: { dogs: [ ] }

I guess the problem is on the map function and the assignment I am doing of the amounts.

```js
const shelterPromises = shelters
    .map((shelter) => {
      const petAmount = randomNumber(1, 10);
      const randomPets = pets.slice(prevIndex, petAmount);
      
      if (randomPets.length) {
        prevIndex = prevIndex + petAmount;
        return ShelterModel.findByIdAndUpdate(shelter._id, {
          dogs: randomPets
        });
      }

      return null;
    })
    .filter(Boolean);

  await Promise.all(shelterPromises);
  console.info('> shelters updated!');
};
```

my full code below:

```js
const faker = require('faker');

const PetModel = require('../models/Pets');
const ShelterModel = require('../models/Shelter');

const randomNumber = (min, max) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

const randomArray = (array) => array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

const randomMonthYear = ['Month', 'Year'];
const randomBreed = [
  'Collie',
  'Podenco',
  'Breton',
  'Mestizo',
  'German Sheperd',
  'Akbash',
  'Husky',
  'Golden Retriever',
  'Basset Hound'
];

const createPets = async (rowsCount) => {
  const pets = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
    const {
      name: { firstName },
      lorem: { paragraph },
      image: { animals },
      date: { past }
    } = faker;

    const name = firstName();
    const age = randomNumber(1, 20).toString();
    const ageMonthYear = randomArray(randomMonthYear);
    const weight = randomNumber(1, 80).toString();
    const img = animals();
    const breed = randomArray(randomBreed);
    const dateArrivalInShelter = past();
    const about = paragraph();

    pets.push(
      new PetModel({
        name,
        age,
        ageMonthYear,
        weight,
        img,
        breed,
        dateArrivalInShelter,
        about
      })
    );
  }

  await PetModel.insertMany(pets);

  console.info('> pets created!');

  const shelters = await ShelterModel.find({});
  let prevIndex = 0;

  const shelterPromises = shelters
    .map((shelter) => {
      const petAmount = randomNumber(1, 10);
      const randomPets = pets.slice(prevIndex, petAmount);
      
      if (randomPets.length) {
        prevIndex = prevIndex + petAmount;
        return ShelterModel.findByIdAndUpdate(shelter._id, {
          dogs: randomPets
        });
      }

      return null;
    })
    .filter(Boolean);

  await Promise.all(shelterPromises);
  console.info('> shelters updated!');
};

const dropPets = async () => {
  await PetModel.deleteMany({});

  console.info('> pets collection deleted!');
};

module.exports = {
  createPets,
  dropPets
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `prevIndex` is increasing at `prevIndex = prevIndex + petAmount` but `petAmount` is always in range `1->10` so after some loop, `prevIndex` will be greater than  `petAmount` and `pets.slice(prevIndex, petAmount)` will just return an empty array. To fix this, you can change your code to:

```
const randomPets = pets.slice(prevIndex, prevIndex + petAmount);
```